# Are "Wrist" blood pressure monitors less accurate then Upper arm?

Tags: blood-pressure

There are *thoughts* that Wrist blood pressure monitors like the one shown below are less accurate than Upper Arm ones. Also, one of the respectable site [mentions](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/high-blood-pressure/expert-answers/wrist-blood-pressure-monitors/faq-20057802) same with reasonable arguments. Is that generally acceptable opinion?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, they are less accurate.**

Mayo Clinic is generally held to be a credible source and in the link you provided they have this to say about wrist monitors:

> Some wrist blood pressure monitors may be accurate if used exactly as
>   directed. However, the American Heart Association recommends using a
>   home blood pressure monitor that measures blood pressure in your upper
>   arm and not using wrist or finger blood pressure monitors.
>
> Wrist blood pressure monitors are extremely sensitive to body
>   position. To get an accurate reading when taking your blood pressure
>   with a wrist monitor, your arm and wrist must be at heart level. Even
>   then, blood pressure measurements taken at the wrist are usually
>   higher and less accurate than those taken at your upper arm.

The American Heart Association has [this](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/high-blood-pressure/understanding-blood-pressure-readings/monitoring-your-blood-pressure-at-home) to say:

> The American Heart Association recommends an automatic, cuff-style,
>   bicep (upper-arm) monitor.
>
> Wrist and finger monitors are not recommended because they yield less
>   reliable readings.

I think those two sources are more than enough to answer the question, but I'll add this as a [third source](https://ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.116.07961):

> The use of wrist devices for home self-measurement, therefore, leads
>   to frequent detection of falsely elevated blood pressure values likely
>   because of a poor memory and rendition of the instructions, leading to
>   the wrong position of the wrist.

And a [fourth](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.119.12674):

> In conclusion, radial systolic BP is not representative of brachial
>   systolic BP, with most participants having a radial systolic BP >5
>   mm Hg higher than brachial and many with differences >15 mm Hg.